# Database design for large volumes of data

Tags: database-design, nosql

My application needs to support multiple users. Each user has a large volume (millions) of data entries. The application needs to select entries based on the current logged-in user.

What is the best SQL database design for such a requirement? To put everything into a single table with an additional `user` field? Or to create a table for each user?

Is NoSQL better in this case?

Comment: Are people accessing the database directly or via an external application?

Comment: @SteBov Not sure what it means. It's a web application and the user just browses webpages. Thus the backend needs to fetch data from database and display them to users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table for each user would be wildly inefficient as whenever a user leaves or joins you need to re-arrange your table structure.

having an `owner_ID` field in the table and then allowing the general users to be identifiable meaning that when someone is logged in the query can run `AND owner_id = @active_user_ID`

Be worth having a table to link the ID to the logged in user, and then you can also set up managers (Table User_ID, Manager_ID,name,detail...) which means you can allow managers to view all data of their underlings (if this is needed)

Its worth noting doing a structure like this to consider indexing the table in a structure that organises the data according to the `owner_id` field to improve performance for each user as they will unlikely overlap

Comment: Yes data from different users don't overlap. My concern with the additional field is that the same value may occupy too much space. If you use NoSQL then user ids don't have to be duplicated. Not sure if SQL engines take care of this storage waste.

Comment: @Cyker are you kidding? The user_id will probably be some 4-byte integer. Have you tried putting the same data in a SQL and a NoSQL/KeyValueStore database and check which needs more space?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Why surprised? If you use user_id as the key in key-value store then it doesn't have to be duplicated which saves you 4 bytes per entry. Testing with 1e6 entries shows the sql database (sqlite) is indeed smaller than the nosql one (mongodb). mongodb does have a limit on max document size, though. But a general kv store doesn't have to suffer the same limit.

Comment: Because normalization in SQL databases means that only keys (Primary/Unique Keys) are duplicated (as FKs in other tables). Nothing else. Whatever other duplication (assuming normalized design) is only for performance (indexes, materialized views, persisted computed columns, etc). In NoSQL (eg Mongo) a lot of things are duplicated (even what would be column names in SQL), resulting in needing more storage space among other things, as your test shows. Why don't you believe your test?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ If there is another 'user' table then user_id is indeed a key. To put it simple, { uid: [val1, val2, ...], } is more space-efficient than [(uid, val1), (uid, val2), ...], right? My test actually proves this. KV store should also be more time-efficient for this type of query unless you build an index for user_id in SQL case. But index is a source of data duplication which costs disk space, you see.

Comment: The various SQL DBMS store the tables in various ways. Heaps, clustered tables, column stores, btree indexes, rtree indexes, hash indexes, bit-map indexes, ... Some of them store data in rows, some in columns, some compressed, etc. They (SQL DBMS) are not all the same (but provide more or less the same interface: SQL) and of course, in many the DBA has many options to choose. So, no, in many DBMS you can have performance with storage efficiency.

Comment: And yes, { uid: [val1, val2, ...], } is more space-efficient than [(uid, val1), (uid, val2), ...]. If the values are actually stored that way. And if you user case is exactly this - and you will never going to need more than one table, and you will never going to search with `where val=?`, then yes, a Key value store is probably the best solution and you don't need a DBMS. But if you have a more complex scenario, then consider it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can share more details on the what type of data you store, and how it is organized we will be able to give better answers..

this may help shed some light on sql vs nosql

[SQL vs NoSQL](https://www.sitepoint.com/sql-vs-nosql-choose/)

As Ste Bov mentioned having separate table for each user is not a good design, it is better to have user id column to identify user.

my two cents